# How to download file in C# with its name?

Tags: c#, webclient

I'm trying to download file from URL using `WebClient`, the problem is that the function `.DownloadFile()` requiring URL, and name that will be given to the saved file, but when we access to the URL it already has the file name.

How can I keep the file name as it is in the URL?

Comment: Can you post your current download code?

Comment: @HenkHolterman: instead of providing numerous options, or just a general answer, a concrete example might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of parsing the url I suggest using function Path.GetFileName():

```
string uri = "http://yourserveraddress/fileName.txt";
string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(uri);
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadFile(uri, fileName);
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work if I understand your question correctly:

```
private string GetFileNameFromUrl(string url)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
        return "image.jpg"; //or throw an ArgumentException

    int sepIndex = url.LastIndexOf("/");

    if(sepIndex == -1)
        return "image.jpg"; //or throw an ArgumentException

    return url.Substring(sepIndex);
}
```

Then you can use it like so:

```
string uri = "http://www.mywebsite.com/res/myimage.jpg";
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadFile(uri, this.GetFileNameFromUrl(uri));
```

If you have no control over the url itself you might want to do some validation on it e.g. Regex.

Comment: Basically. Some sanitizing/processing might be advisable.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
string url = "http://www.mywebsite.com/res/myimage.jpg?guid=2564";
Uri uri = new Uri(url);
string fileName = uri.Segments.Last();
```

*Note*: Last() is the extension method from Linq.